# How to make a cut in a via

Tags: altium

I want to make a cut in the via like this image:

[image]

I'm using Altium to develop.

I was recommended to make the via "castellation" but I can't find how to make this via in the center of the board.

Does someone know more about "castellation" and can help me make this via with cut in the center of the board?

I'm making a six-axis sensor.

They have three vias with cuts, to result in six signals to read. It doesn't exactly have to be done by "castellation", but castellation was the only way I found.

[image]

Comment: There really must be an easier way to accomplish what your trying to do than cutting a via like that.  Perhaps you should share more about why you need to do this.

Comment: i'm making a six-axis sensor. They have three vias with cut, to result in six signals for read. it doesn't exactly have to be done by "castellated", but the only way I found was this, I would like new tips

Comment: To continue @Scott request... you'll likely save time and money if you can share more data, or a datasheet, of the sensor.  On the surface, this seems like an overcomplicated and unnecessary requirement of the device.

Comment: I am basing on the PCB of this article, the purpose of operation is the same https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9140324

Comment: What is the size of this hole? I doubt it is a via *per se*, more like a (partially) plated through-hole.

Comment: the diameter of this hole is 2,2mm

Answer (score 7):

You would generate the plated through hole of the appropriate size, and specify a slot in the appropriate board layer.  You would need to chat with the fabricator to make sure the slot is cut *after* the hole is plated.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the closest to standard process. The hole is a standard plated hole and the drilled slot can be specified as unplated so it will be created later (usually there's a separate drill file created for unplated holes). They'll probably want to verify that's actually what you want since the slot and plated hole overlap.

Comment: Often the PCB manufacturers will request the slot to be drawn on edge cuts layer. But best still to ask the specific manufacturer.

Answer (score 6):

From the picture, the via has holes milled into it after the board is otherwise finished.  This can probably be done in the same manufacturing step as drilling any unplated mounting holes, but it requires a precision machine, and it must be done with a milling cutter, not a drill (a standard twist drill does not drill straight when it's drilling "half a hole").

You either need to buy the board with the vias uncut and file them out by hand (assuming that they're big enough for you to get in there with a jeweler's file), or you need to find a PCB manufacturer who's willing to make those cuts -- then you need to add your own layer of quality control to the PCB manufacturer's, until you're sure that they're actually doing the job right.

Comment: This can be accomplished end-of-line concurrently with depanelization by specifying a routing process. This is certainly extra money, but is not a significant premium to add another tool touch if you are already routing.

Comment: The paper doesn't show dimensions, but it might be useful for the OP to NOT think of this as a via.  There won't be any reliable way to automate fabrication, as you say.

Comment: I didn't say that reliable automatic fabrication couldn't be done -- just that it's an extra step, and the PCB manufacturer has to be on their toes.

Answer (score 0):

Castellation technology and other special requirements like yours have to be negotiated with the PCB manufacturer.

To make castellated vias, manufacturers add a couple of extra steps in the manufacturing flow.

The extra cost is in the order of 10 to 20%.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would be to talk to your PCB supplier and ask them the best way to do a nonstandard modification to the board because it's likely that they would have to mill or drill the extra slot which requires an addtional step after the vias have been plated.

Let's talk about layers

However the way to do this in altium would be to add a slot to the board outline layer through the plated through hole.  The pads of the part should not extend the hole inside of the board outline layer.

Another way this could be done is add two non plated holes on the side of the plated through hole(which could be a problem because small drill bits can break on contact with metal. I don't think this would work very well and the PCB manufacturer might not be happy about it.

You might also have to make special rules for the DRC as it will flag either of these.